# Scheduled action fails, but same immediate action succeeds

Tags: visual-workflow

I am trying to add a Contact to a Campaign, using a flow to check that the campaign member does not already exist. If I configure the action as immediate, the flow succeeds in creating a new campaign member. If I make it a scheduled action (with exact same variable parameters), the flow fails with this error: 
This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records:

> ContactId FROM CampaignMember WHERE (((CampaignId = ' 701i0000000yEOfAAM ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:63 invalid ID field: 701i0000000yEOfAAM . For details, see API Exceptions

Comment: mmm...have you tried using the process builder to add the contact rather than a flow?  idk why it fails, but might as well give it a try.